# What is the difference between "in time" and "on time"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-meaning, word-difference

> We reached the station **on time**.
>
> We reached the station **in time**.

I think first one means we reached at particular point of time when we are required to reach.

And second means we reached before the required time.

Am I right? Or is there any other difference or meaning?
If so, Please explain to me. And please explain me the points of grammer related to this.

Comment: Any dictionary will provide a good answer. See [this link](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/on--time?s=t).

Comment: Each of the usages, _in time_ and _on time,_ is specifically, and clearly, explained at that link, and with examples. You have not read it thoroughly.

Comment: In dictionaries you can often find phrases and idioms related to a specific word. In this case, you should seek "in time" and "on time". 1:http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in-time
2: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Required time" is a little vague, so I will not use those terms. I assume that you are traveling to a train station, not necessarily by train, to catch a train, for example.

> [on time](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+time)
>    According to schedule; punctual or punctually.

I assume this is your schedule (it does not have to be). So, if you planned to arrive at the station at 9 am, and you arrived at 9, then you would be *on time*. The implication is that you planned to arrive at the station *before* your train departed.

> [in time](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+time)
>   Before a time limit expires, early enough

There is generally an *implied* "for" or "event" when using *in time*.
So, for example,

> 1. We reached the station in time ***to catch the train***.
> 2. We reached the station in time ***for check-in***.

So for example, you plan to arrive at the station by 9am to catch the 11am train. The traffic was awful, but you finally arrived at 10:30am and barely caught the 11am train. You were not *on time* (with respect to you schedule) but you were *in time* to catch the train.

I believe this is a matter of idiomatic use and not so much grammar. The difference has also been discussed on ELU: [“In time” versus “on time”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17436/in-time-versus-on-time).

Answer (score 2):

The simple difference:

**on time** refers only to *scheduled* things.

**in time** can refer either to scheduled or unscheduled things

**On time**  means "punctual".

**In time** means "not too late".

> He was on time for the scheduled interview.
>
> He arrived in time to extinguish the fire before it spread.
>
> He arrived in time to catch the last train.